# Roblox Studio Game Pass Purchase Failed

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a Lua script that is supposed to prompt the player with a gamepads purchase, but it doesn't work. It is in a normal script. Here is the code and the error:

```
local productId = 6657664
local donateButton = script.Parent

local function buy(player)
    game:GetService("MarketplaceService"):PromptGamePassPurchase(player, productId)
end

donateButton.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(buy)
```

[Error here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgyvV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive it's a roblox error not a script error.